# slime won't spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know this has been covered. But I have used chunk finder and an app on my phone to find chunks. I have built several 16 by 16 3 high below level 39 chunks.I also built an elaborate slime farm all the way down to bedrock with levels every 3 high.all in spots that chunk finder said is a slime chunk.I am at least 30 blocks away from the chunks and I still get no slimes to spawn.

Comment: What biome are you in?

Comment: Right now the last one is savanna. I have also built one in the swamp that was supposed to be a slime chunk

Comment: It should work in the swamp. How's the lighting?

Comment: Over 10 that is where I built my slime farm and I get nothing

Comment: Did you build the swamp farm aboveground? (Slimes won't spawn belowground in swamps.) Also, is this slime chunk finder you used current? Since worldgen changed with 1.7, it's *possible* (but not something I've checked up on) that slime chunks are calculated differently than before.

Answer (score 0):

> Slimes spawn in specific chunks below layer 40. They can also spawn in swamp biomes between layers 50-70 in light levels of 7 or less.
>
> Like other hostile mobs, slimes will not spawn within 24 blocks (spherical) of any player, and will despawn over time if no player is within 32 blocks and instantly if no player is within 128 blocks.
>
> Like most other mobs, slimes require two vertical non-opaque blocks (e.g., air, signs, torches) to spawn in, with an opaque block underneath. The space they spawn in must also be clear of solid obstructions and liquids.[Verify] Big slimes require a 3×2½×3 space to spawn, small slimes require a 3×2×3 space, and tiny slimes require a 1×2×1 space (or 1×1×1 if the upper block is not opaque).

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Spawning

Answer (score -4):

You need to be at height 11 for slime to spawn and they usually spawn during night

Comment: They are supposed to spawn at level 40 to 0 also. in the swamp I built my farm above ground at the level it says they will spawn and from level 39 to 5 but no spawns

Comment: Neither of those facts are true

Comment: Really everything I have read says that. Then what is true

Comment: @imulsion are you referring to dave's comment or the content of the answer?

Comment: @Ben The answer, sorry if I gave the wrong impression

Comment: also apologies @dave you have correct information